# Rails v6.0, new app -- scaffold is generating controller test errors upon setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using `Rails 6.0.3.2 and Ruby 2.7.1.p83` to build a data scaffold for a new app. After creating the app, I generate a series of ~60 scaffolds - each having a single 'name' (string) field - via the command line.

`Rails db:migrate` is no problem. When I invoke `rails test`, I get 2 fails out of 527 assertions. Both are `NoMethodErrors` (a missing `count` method) in a "Behaviors" controller.

This occurs on only 1 of the 60-ish scaffolds, which are meant to be (at this point) identically built.

This definitely wasn't expected. Anybody seen this before?

*error message from `rails test:`*

```
BehaviorsControllerTest#test_should_create_behavior:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'count' for ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior:Module
    test/controllers/behaviors_controller_test.rb:19:in 'block in <class:BehaviorsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/behaviors_controller_test.rb:19:in 'block in <class:BehaviorsControllerTest>'

rails test test/controllers/behaviors_controller_test.rb:18

E

Error:
BehaviorsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_behavior:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'count' for ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior:Module
    test/controllers/behaviors_controller_test.rb:42:in 'block in <class:BehaviorsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/behaviors_controller_test.rb:42:in 'block in <class:BehaviorsControllerTest>'
```

*controller test clauses:*

```
test "should create behavior" do
    assert_difference('Behavior.count') do
      post behaviors_url, params: { behavior: { name: @behavior.name } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to behavior_url(Behavior.last)
  end
```

```
test "should destroy behavior" do
    assert_difference('Behavior.count', -1) do
      delete behavior_url(@behavior)
    end

    assert_redirected_to behaviors_url
  end
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of the concerned test, the tested class and the error log please?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bjpcjp/73c9f2048fe174ec335c891815731778

Comment: You should paste the snippet in your question please. Also could you paste the snippet of the test that fails please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen a name that conflicts with a Rails built-in object: `Behavior`.

There is a module called [`ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest/Behavior.html).

Tests are (presumably) being evaluated inside a method defined in the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` module, so that Ruby's constant lookup finds `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior` before traversing up to your top-level constant.

You need to use the scope resolution operator (`::`) to reference the top-level constant:

```
assert_difference('::Behavior.count') do
  post behaviors_url, params: { behavior: { name: @behavior.name } }
end
```

Comment: "Behavior" is a somewhat arbitrary name for the object that I'm building - renaming it is the (somewhat) easier approach.

I spun up a standalone Rails 6.0.2.3 app, generated a "Behavior" scaffold, and re-ran `rails test`. Same error.

Thanks a lot for pointing out the ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest::Behavior angle.